# Is there an irreducible quartic over $\mathbb{Q}$ whose splitting field is not radical?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field, galois-extensions

It is well known that there are degree 3 irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb Q$ whose splitting fields are not radical. Indeed, there are examples where the splitting field is a real Galois extension of degree 3 and real Galois extensions over $\mathbb Q$ of odd degree cannot be radical.

I was wondering if there are degree 4 irreducible polynomials $f\in \mathbb Q [x]$ whose splitting fields $L$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ are not radical. If the Galois group $G$ of $L$ over $\mathbb Q$ were isomorphic to any transitive subgroup of $S_4$ aside from $A_4$ and $S_4$, then certainly $L$ is radical. This is because these subgroups have a chain of subgroups that are index 2 from each other. The fundamental theorem of Galois theory then allows us to obtain $L$ via consecutive quadratic extensions (and quadratic extensions are radical).

The cases for when $G$ is isomorphic to $S_4$ or $A_4$ remain as possibilities for an example. I was thinking along the lines of finding an irreducible quartic with four real roots having either $S_4$ or $A_4$ as Galois groups, and then adapting the proof of casus irreducibilis. However, I cannot seem to come up with anything.

Comment: I’m afraid you won’t find anything, since $S_4$ (and therefore $A_4$) are both solvable. Consider the composition series $1 \subset V \subset A_4 \subset S_4$ where $V \subset A_4$ is the normal subgroup made with the identity and the three bitranspositions.

Comment: Solvability implies the splitting field $L$ is contained in a radical extension. However, this does not imply $L$ itself is radical. Some splitting fields of some degree 3 irreducible polynomials show this to be the case, such as the degree 3 subfield over $\mathbb Q$ Of the 7th cyclotomic extension.

Comment: Oh. Good point. Then perhaps consider https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/4.4.7537.1 . It’s a totally real number field with group $S_4$, and very little ramification (a single prime), so I’d guess it can’t be radical. Similarly, https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/4.4.26569.1 is totally real ramified at a single prime with group $A_4$ so shouldn’t be radical either.